# Errore in javax.xml.trasformer when change java version from 1.6 to 1.8

Tags: java

i have the necessity to pass from java 1.6 to java 1.8 .
when I run the original program in 1.6 all go well, if i try in 1.8 i get back NullPointerException.

here the program:

```
        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(byte_porzione_xml);
        isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        xif.setXMLResolver(new DummyEntityResolver());
        xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(isr);
              
        xsr.nextTag();
         
        DOMResult domResult = new DOMResult();
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(new StAXSource(xsr), domResult);

        Document doc = (Document) domResult.getNode();
```

Here the stack error:

javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:343)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.interventi.tecnici.CaricaPorzioneXMLLettura.load(CaricaPorzioneXMLLettura.java:50)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.interventi.tecnici.InterventoTecnicoBase.runAggiornamentoPPI(InterventoTecnicoBase.java:113)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.interventi.tecnici.InterventoTecnicoBase.run(InterventoTecnicoBase.java:89)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.ImportatoreConsumi_Letture.InsertData(ImportatoreConsumi_Letture.java:1997)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.ImportatoreBaseXml.processaFile(ImportatoreBaseXml.java:207)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.ImportatoreBase.DoProcessFile(ImportatoreBase.java:542)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.ImportatoreAziendale.DoProcessFile(ImportatoreAziendale.java:447)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.ImportatoreBase.DoProcessaFileDaFolder(ImportatoreBase.java:461)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.ImportatoreBase.ProcessaFileDaFolder(ImportatoreBase.java:413)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.ImportatoreBase.run(ImportatoreBase.java:349)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.setXmlVersion(CoreDocumentImpl.java:901)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.setDocumentInfo(SAX2DOM.java:143)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.startElement(SAX2DOM.java:153)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler.closeStartTag(ToXMLSAXHandler.java:208)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler.characters(ToXMLSAXHandler.java:528)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.StAXStream2SAX.handleCharacters(StAXStream2SAX.java:245)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.StAXStream2SAX.bridge(StAXStream2SAX.java:152)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.StAXStream2SAX.parse(StAXStream2SAX.java:101)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:679)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:728)
... 11 more
```

---

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.setXmlVersion(CoreDocumentImpl.java:901)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.setDocumentInfo(SAX2DOM.java:143)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.startElement(SAX2DOM.java:153)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler.closeStartTag(ToXMLSAXHandler.java:208)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler.characters(ToXMLSAXHandler.java:528)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.StAXStream2SAX.handleCharacters(StAXStream2SAX.java:245)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.StAXStream2SAX.bridge(StAXStream2SAX.java:152)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.StAXStream2SAX.parse(StAXStream2SAX.java:101)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:679)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:728)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:343)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.interventi.tecnici.CaricaPorzioneXMLLettura.load(CaricaPorzioneXMLLettura.java:50)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.interventi.tecnici.InterventoTecnicoBase.runAggiornamentoPPI(InterventoTecnicoBase.java:113)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.interventi.tecnici.InterventoTecnicoBase.run(InterventoTecnicoBase.java:89)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.ImportatoreConsumi_Letture.InsertData(ImportatoreConsumi_Letture.java:1997)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.ImportatoreBaseXml.processaFile(ImportatoreBaseXml.java:207)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.ImportatoreBase.DoProcessFile(ImportatoreBase.java:542)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.ImportatoreAziendale.DoProcessFile(ImportatoreAziendale.java:447)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.ImportatoreBase.DoProcessaFileDaFolder(ImportatoreBase.java:461)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.ImportatoreBase.ProcessaFileDaFolder(ImportatoreBase.java:413)
at it.sistematica.e360.mdimporter.ImportatoreBase.run(ImportatoreBase.java:349)

Comment: Maybe this is the cause: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8016914

Comment: now i try a different version of java 1.8.. seems was a bug in the official version

Answer (score 0):

The shared data is not sufficient to understand the error. Share little XML data

Comment: see comment below

Comment: Hi Paolo, Try to run your application in JDK 14. It will work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
unfortunately the production machine at the customer's will can only have a java version installed and that chosen was 1.8.
most likely some bugs that arose from 1.7 onwards must have been solved and implemented.

Comment: The issue is still there in JDK 8_261 and It will work in JDK 11

Comment: I created a workaround like this:                                                                 private static Document convertStringToDocument(String xmlStr) {
         DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
         DocumentBuilder builder;  
         try   {  
             builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
             Document doc = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( xmlStr ) ) ); 
             return doc;
         } catch (Exception e) {  
             e.printStackTrace();  
         } 
         return null;
     }

Answer (score 0):

```
 <DatiPod>
   <Pod>ITXXXXXXXX</Pod>
   <DataMisura>31/07/2020</DataMisura>
   <DatiPdp>
      <Trattamento>F</Trattamento>
      <Tensione>220</Tensione>
      <PotContrImp>3,000</PotContrImp>
      <PotDisp>3,300</PotDisp>
      <Ka>1,000</Ka>
    <Kr>1,000</Kr>
    <Kp>1,000</Kp>
    <MatrAtt>xxxxxxx</MatrAtt>
    <MatrRea>xxxxxxx</MatrRea>
    <MatrPot>xxxxxx</MatrPot>
    <DataInstMisAtt>28/08/2007</DataInstMisAtt>
    <DataInstMisRea>28/08/2007</DataInstMisRea>
    <DataInstMisPot>28/08/2007</DataInstMisPot>
    <CifreAtt>6</CifreAtt>
    <CifreRea>6</CifreRea>
    <CifrePot>6</CifrePot>
    <GruppoMis>SI</GruppoMis>
    <Forfait>NO</Forfait>
    </DatiPdp>
    <Misura>
    <Raccolta>P</Raccolta>
    <TipoDato>E</TipoDato>
    <Validato>S</Validato>
    <EaF1>5557,776</EaF1>
    <EaF2>5432,375</EaF2>
    <EaF3>13574,698</EaF3>
    <ErF1>3007,983</ErF1>
    <ErF2>2360,521</ErF2>
    <PotF1>1,128</PotF1>
    <PotF2>0,956</PotF2>
    <PotF3>0,944</PotF3>
    </Misura>
    </DatiPod>
```